# What effect does the resistance of the fuse have on the output voltage of a voltage divider?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, fuses

For the figure shown below, I want to know how the fuse affects output voltage when the input voltage is swept within a safe range. Theoretically the output voltage should stay the same, but will it change at all in a real world scenario?
[image]

Comment: The fuse has a resistance. So, change it to a resistor, say R1. Then let's call the 10 Ohm R2. Vout = V(t) * R2 / (R1+R2). That is the voltage divider formula. If you know I out, you can also use that to calculate the voltage. Vout(t) = V(t) - Iout(t) * R1. Fuses have a temperature coefficient, but you probably don't need to worry about that unless you are getting near the point where you are going to blow the fuse.

Comment: Any fuse, in order to work, must dissipate energy. So there must be *some* impact. But they can be designed so that the energy accumulates rapidly, raising the temperature quickly enough to be useful, at the rated current. They also won't drop much voltage at the rated current (or usually shouldn't.) See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical)

Comment: It is ridiculous to say that fuses typically have resistances below 50 mOhm. It totally depends on the fuse. Some PTC's for low current have several Ohms of resistance. One fuse I dealt with, I think it was an 0603 fuse for 1A, had around 400 mOhm, as I recall. The resistance depends on many factors. If you want to know what it is, look it up or measure it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Theoretically the output voltage should stay the same, but will it
>   change at all in a real world scenario?

Yes it will, because any real world fuse has resistance. And this resistance will also change with temperature.

Next question: how much resistance has a fuse? Well, it depends on its type and on its voltage, current and \$I^2t\$ ratings. The nominal "cold" resistance (i.e., at < 10% rated current) can range from < 10 milliOhms **up to several Ohms**.

As an example, look at this [Littelfuse catalog](https://stevenengineering.com/tech_support/PDFs/28FUSECP.pdf). A sample page from it:

[image: sample fuse]

### Conclusion

you must select an appropriate fuse for your application in order to avoid having any significant and undesired voltage drop in it when connected to your load.

Comment: Nice addition. For those interested in learning more about the term, \$I^2 s\$, the units are the same as "Joules per Ohm." It is also known as the "action integral of a pulse" and it makes sense mostly when it is the case that nearly all of the energy is devoted to raising the temperature (where no useful portion of the heat is allowed to have time needed to significantly flow into its surroundings.)